# Add ACF to custom function

Tags: php, function, advanced-custom-fields

I need to add my ACF field to a custom function. I have tried this but there is  syntax error.

```
add_action( 'flatsome_custom_single_product_1', function () {
    echo <?php the_field('designer'); ?>;
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling the_field('designer') outside the actual post loop, you need to pass the post ID as well.
Here is the [Ref](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).

For your case, you can achieve this by using the code like below

```
add_action( 'flatsome_custom_single_product_1', function () {
global $post;
echo  get_field('designer', $post->ID);
} );
```

Comment: Thank you. Since this will be added to a product on WooCommerce, how would I make it global for all product types?

Comment: As I understand from your code, you have been using flatsome_custom_single_product_1 hook. If this hook is not available in all product page, then you can use the right hook name there depending on the position where you want to show the content. Here you can see the woocommerce hook references https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html#hooks-template-files